# Firebase CLI deploy functions - Error: Failed to initialize a region

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm having trouble doing `firebase deploy --only functions` for an app on Blaze plan.
I have the latest firebase-tools CLI  (v 3.5.0).

I get the following error:

```
=== Deploying to 'myapp1234'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (1.29 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  starting release process (may take several minutes)...
i  functions: updating function myFunc...
⚠  functions[myFunc]: Deploy Error: Failed to initialize a region


Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

I've retried this every half hour for the past 12 hours, thinking there's an outage. The firebase status page shows all green.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here's what I found, a little weird:

`firebase list` shows all the firebase projects you have access to, BUT they are not already available (i.e. added as alias to your current folder project).

Even if the firebase-tools CLI allows you to do `firebase deploy --project myproject1`, if you **do not have** `myproject1` declared in `.firebaserc` => it will fail with the weird region error above.

To fix this, I found that there are 2 options:

- `firebase use --add` (will trigger an interactive list)
- `firebase use myproject1`

=> and then `firebase deploy --project myproject1` will work  (with or without the optional `--only functions`)

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me, is there anything else I could try?

Comment: @gomezluisj did you find a solution? I also tried the above and it sis not solve the issue.

Comment: @jasan yes, I wrote google and they solved it, took two weeks btw.

Comment: @gomezluisj you wrote google? did they fix it specifically for you?!

Comment: @VictorFerreira I used firebase support to contact them,  and two weeks later they wrote back after they fixed the issue, it was a problem on their end, so i assume it was affecting several customers not just me.

Comment: Thanx it Fix for Me

Comment: After an hour of head scratching this ends up being the solution, thanks!