# Cloud Functions for Firebase - deploy error - Failed to initialize a region?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm in the process of uploading some Cloud Functions for Firebase via the Firebase CLI. I have my `functions` folder setup and everything is correct. :I actually use this exact functions folder in another project but for whatever reason in this particular project, when I run `firebase deploy --only functions`, I get this:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (972 B) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  starting release process (may take several minutes)...
i  functions: updating function getUserByEmail...
⚠  functions[getUserByEmail]: Deploy Error: Failed to initialize a region


Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Does anyone know what this error means?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/43091258/4815718

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for this. This never showed up in my searches, but I'll investigate and let you know!